# How to create and assign a callback function for a Python Swigged C++ object

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a swigged C++ class (acting as a a plugin with events) that carry pointers to assignable callback functions, e.g.

```
typedef void (*PluginEvent)(void* data1, void* data2);

class PluginWithEvents :  public Plugin
{
    public:
        bool assignOnProgressEvent(PluginEvent pluginsProgress, void* userData1 = nullptr, void* userData2 = nullptr);
        void workProgressEvent(void* data1, void* data2);
    protected:
        PluginEvent mWorkProgressEvent;
        void* mWorkProgressData1;
        void* mWorkProgressData2;
};
```

and implementation code

```
void PluginWithEvents::workProgressEvent(void* data1, void* data2)
{
    if(mWorkProgressEvent)
    {
        mWorkProgressEvent(data1, data2);
    }
}

bool PluginWithEvents::assignOnProgressEvent(PluginEvent progress, void* userData1, void* userData2)
{
    mWorkProgressEvent = progress;
    mWorkProgressData1 = userData1;
    mWorkProgressData2 = userData2;
    return true;
}
```

Question is, when using this class in Python, how do I define the callback function to be passed to the assignProgressEvent function?

The following Python code gives errors:

```
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded 
function 'PluginWithEvents_assignOnProgressEvent'.

Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
PluginWithEvents::assignOnProgressEvent(dsl::PluginEvent,void *,void *)
PluginWithEvents::assignOnProgressEvent(dsl::PluginEvent,void *)
PluginWithEvents::assignOnProgressEvent(dsl::PluginEvent)
```

Comment: Do you want to pass a Python function as callback or do you want to pass a C++ function pointer via the Python interface?

Comment: While in Python, a custom Python function would be nice to pass, if that is possible?

Comment: That is possible, I've done [something similar before](https://github.com/hmenke/cpp-patterns/tree/master/python_callback) but mapping to C++ function pointers it is not fun and will involve global static variables (which can easily cause linkage and concurrency problems).

Comment: Thanks for your example. I'll look closer at it. Looks quite complex. :)

Comment: Those people who downvote and vote to close without leaving a comment are the best.

Comment: These downvoters and closers should be suspended from the ability to give votes and closing, if not a reasonable reason is given..

Answer (score 2):

I have prepared an example of what I mentioned in the comments.  It has become quite monstrous and it's probably rather fragile.  There are a lot of places where error checking could be improved significantly.

In the interface file I include the backend code (`test.hpp`) which is more or less the one from your question and the tools which I need for the Python callback.  All the nasty details are hidden in `python_callback.hpp`.

Then I declare a **global** variable `callback` which holds the current callback and a function `callback_caller` which calls the callback.  You can already notice one of the shortcomings of this approach here.  There can at most be one callback in flight at any time.  So don't pass more than one callback to a function and don't hold on to a reference or pointer to `callback` (copies might be okay, but no guarantees).

The rest is typemaps to map Python functions to C++ function pointers.

---

**`test.i`**

```
%module example
%{
#include <iostream>

#include "test.hpp"
#include "python_callback.hpp"

PythonCallback callback;

void callback_caller(void *, void *) {
    double pi = callback.call<double>("ABC", 3.14, 42);
    std::cout << "C++ reveived: " << pi << '\n';
}
%}

%include <exception.i>
%exception {
  try {
    $action
  } catch (std::exception const &e) {
    SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, e.what());
  }
}

%typemap(typecheck) PluginEvent {
    $1 = PyCallable_Check($input);

}
%typemap(in) PluginEvent {
    callback = PythonCallback($input);
    $1 = &callback_caller;
}

%include "test.hpp"
```

**`test.hpp`**

```
#pragma once

typedef void (*PluginEvent)(void *data1, void *data2);

class PluginWithEvents {
public:
    bool assignOnProgressEvent(PluginEvent pluginsProgress,
                               void *userData1 = nullptr,
                               void *userData2 = nullptr) {
        mWorkProgressEvent = pluginsProgress;
        mWorkProgressData1 = userData1;
        mWorkProgressData2 = userData2;
        return true;
    }
    void workProgressEvent(void *data1, void *data2) {
        if (mWorkProgressEvent) {
            mWorkProgressEvent(data1, data2);
        }
    }

protected:
    PluginEvent mWorkProgressEvent = nullptr;
    void *mWorkProgressData1 = nullptr;
    void *mWorkProgressData2 = nullptr;
};
```

**`python_callback.hpp`**

This file is very incomplete in the sense that mappings between all the different Python and C++ types are missing.  I added a few mappings (`PyFloat` to `double`, PyInt`to`int`, PyString` to `std::string`) in both ways to give you a blueprint how to extend the code with your own mappings.

```
#pragma once
#include <Python.h>

#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

namespace internal {

// Convert C++ type to Python (add your favourite overloads)

inline PyObject *arg_to_python(double x) { return PyFloat_FromDouble(x); }
inline PyObject *arg_to_python(int v) { return PyInt_FromLong(v); }
inline PyObject *arg_to_python(std::string const &s) {
    return PyString_FromStringAndSize(s.c_str(), s.size());
}

// Convert Python type to C++ (add your favourite specializations)

template <typename T>
struct return_from_python {
    static T convert(PyObject *);
};

template <>
void return_from_python<void>::convert(PyObject *) {}

template <>
double return_from_python<double>::convert(PyObject *result) {
    if (!PyFloat_Check(result)) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("type is not PyFloat");
    }
    return PyFloat_AsDouble(result);
}

template <>
int return_from_python<int>::convert(PyObject *result) {
    if (!PyInt_Check(result)) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("type is not PyInt");
    }
    return PyInt_AsLong(result);
}

template <>
std::string return_from_python<std::string>::convert(PyObject *result) {
    char *buffer;
    Py_ssize_t len;
    if (PyString_AsStringAndSize(result, &buffer, &len) == -1) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("type is not PyString");
    }
    return std::string{buffer, static_cast<std::size_t>(len)};
}

// Scope Guard

template <typename F>
struct ScopeGuard_impl {
    F f;
    ScopeGuard_impl(F f) : f(std::move(f)) {}
    ~ScopeGuard_impl() { f(); }
};

template <typename F>
inline ScopeGuard_impl<F> ScopeGuard(F &&f) {
    return ScopeGuard_impl<F>{std::forward<F>(f)};
}

} // namespace internal

class PythonCallback {
    PyObject *callable = nullptr;

public:
    PythonCallback() = default;
    PythonCallback(PyObject *obj) : callable(obj) { Py_INCREF(obj); }
    ~PythonCallback() { Py_XDECREF(callable); }

    PythonCallback(PythonCallback const &other) : callable(other.callable) {
        Py_INCREF(callable);
    }

    PythonCallback &operator=(PythonCallback other) noexcept {
        if (this != &other) {
            std::swap(this->callable, other.callable);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // Function caller
    template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    ReturnType call(Args const &... args) {
        using internal::arg_to_python;
        using internal::return_from_python;
        using internal::ScopeGuard;

        PyGILState_STATE gil = PyGILState_Ensure();
        auto gil_ = ScopeGuard([&]() { PyGILState_Release(gil); });

        PyObject *const result = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(
            callable, arg_to_python(args)..., nullptr);
        auto result_ = ScopeGuard([&]() { Py_XDECREF(result); });

        if (result == nullptr) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Executing Python callback failed!");
        }

        return return_from_python<ReturnType>::convert(result);
    }
};
```

We can test the above setup using a little script which hopefully prints “Hello World!”.

**`test.py`**

```python
from example import *

p = PluginWithEvents()

def callback(a, b, c):
    print("Hello World!")
    print(a,type(a))
    print(b,type(b))
    print(c,type(c))
    return 3.14

p.assignOnProgressEvent(callback)
p.workProgressEvent(None,None)
```

Let's try it

```
$ swig -c++ -python test.i
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++11 -I /usr/include/python2.7/ -fPIC -shared test_wrap.cxx -o _example.so -lpython2.7
$ python test.py
Hello World!
('ABC', <type 'str'>)
(3.14, <type 'float'>)
(42L, <type 'long'>)
C++ reveived: 3.14
```

Comment: Thanks Henri, That's pretty awesome! It will take me some time to grasp the template stuff! If I can get it to work with my old compiler, bcc32, I will use it. In the example, the callback don't have any arguments. I assume it can take arguments and that the return_from_python is for that?

Comment: I'll mark this the answer if no other answers are submitted in a day or so!

Comment: @TotteKarlsson I have updated my answer with a simpler Python object call, more type mappings, and a return value showcase.

Comment: @TotteKarlsson This does not work in Python 3, by the way, because the C-API changed quite a lot between 2 and 3.  Especially integers are all `PyLong` instead of `PyInt` and all strings are unicode rather than bytes.

Comment: @TotteKarlsson Also the code will *not work* with bcc32 because it has [no support for variadic templates and lambda expressions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/C%2B%2B11_Language_Features_Compliance_Status) (and no initializer list, but those could be avoided).  If you can use the Clang-enhanced bcc32c you'll have access to all these features.